# Solve border width problem in itext pdf table in java

Tags: java, itext

I'm using itext5 and when I set the border width for the table I get an issue like below:

[image]

This way I used to making the pdf cell:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("SUBSTATION",f));
cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
cell.setColspan(2);
cell.setBorderWidth(2);
cell.setFixedHeight(30f);
table.addCell(cell);
```

and for the second cell should be under the complete border surrounded i used the following code:
`cell.setBorderWidthLeft(2);`

How can I modify this issue?

Comment: Please share the relevant part of your code, so we could assist you

Comment: I described more about my problem